# Blood Relations

Tags: logical-deduction, family

L, M, N, O, T, U, V and W are eight members of a family.
They belong to three different generations.
There are three married couples.
They are all sitting around a circular table facing the center, but not necessarily in same manner.
N and L are children of O.
L is not the immediate neighbour of his mother.
O and U are a married couple.
O, the wife of U, sits second to the left of her husband.
There is only one person sitting between N and his niece V, but that person is not V's father.
T, a bachelor, sits third to the right of his uncle L, but neither to the opposite nor to the immediate left of his father.
V is not the immediate neighbour of her Aunt M.
No three females are sitting together.
N and his sister in law are immediate neighbours.

**Someone please guide me though a step by step answer for this question.**

Comment: just out of curiosity, is this a puzzle you've made up or did it come from somewhere else? (If it came from somewhere else, where?)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I have got the answer.

> Going clockwise: O,M,L,V,W,N,U,T

Explanations:
First:

> First we deduce the family tree. From the statements, O and U are married. L and N are their **sons**. V is the daughter of L and T is the son of N. M is the wife of N and W is the wife of L.

Now, their positions:

> First, we put O at any arbitrary position in a circle.(Draw a circle and mark 8 points equidistant) Note that We can place O at any arbitrary position because circles can be rotated and hence, it would make no difference to the final answer. However, had it been a straight line, The initial positions of O and U would matter. Place U such that O is two positions to the left of U.

Secondly:

> Now comes the hard part. From the given statements, we can place L at 3 positions only(directly opposite to O, directly Opposite to U, to the immediate right of U). We can see easily that if we place L For "next to U", there is no position for N to be placed.Similarly, directly Opposite to O is also ruled out. Hence, only place is "Directly Opposite to U" for L.

Thirdly:

> Place N now. Similarly there are 4 places for N. (To the immediate right of L, to the immediate left of L, Opposite to O, immediate right of U.) It can't be to the right of L, since then, it would be between L and O. But, it has to be immediately next to W(Sister-in-Law). The V statement rules out two of the other options. Hence, N is seated to the immediate right of U.

Next:

> V is now placed. It is placed to the right of L, two places away from N as given. W is placed in between V and N since she is the immediate neighbour of N. M is the last one remaining and is thus placed between O and L.

Here's a picture of the arrangement:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the family tree.

> O is the wife of U. N and L are their sons. 
> M is the wife of N and W is the wife of L. 
> V is the daughter of L and W. T is the son of M and N. I haven't solved the family tree. Got an exam tomorrow. :)